# Suppose $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M=A+iB$ for $M\in\mathbb{C}.$ What condition must $A$ and $B$ be to satisfy $M$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra

So far, I have AA^H=AA^T-iAB^T+iBA^T+BB^T. I have a feeling that A and B must be orthogonal. I just can't grasp what the other two terms must be. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have $A,B\in\mathbb R$, or do you have $A,B\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ for some $n$?

Comment: It just says A,B∈ℝ

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both orthogonal, then surely $C$ can't be unitary.

Comment: If $A,B\in\mathbb R$ then they are just numbers and your question is for a complex number $z$, when is it true that $z^\dagger z=1$? The answer to this is whenever $|z|=1$, i.e. $A^2+B^2=1$.

Comment: If AB^T=BA^T, i.e. AB^T is symmetric, then the middle terms cancel out. Is there a term for when AA^T=0?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If $A\in\mathbb R$ then $A$ is a number and $A^T=A$, assuming $T$ is signifying the transpose operation. Also $AB=BA$ for $A,B\in\mathbb R$.